# How to extract the root CA certificate from keyvault certificate using command?

Tags: ssl-certificate, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, client-certificates, azure-application-gateway

I have a certificate in the azure key vault. I want to use the root certificate of this certificate in backend settings of application gateway.

I already used the keyvault certificate in listener for TLS termination with Application gateway ARM template using property "sslCertificate".

I want to know whether there is any option to use the certificate from keyvault and extract root certificate from it using ARM template to use in backend https settings of application gateway?

I want to know if there is any powershell command or ARM template option to extract the root certificate from the keyvault?

I want these to automate the deployment process and not do it manually.

I tried to upload the root certificate manually after downloading the certificate in local machine as per the link [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/extracting-ca-root-certificate-digital-certificate) and it is working fine manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results below:***

Created a keyvault with certificate using powershell like below:

```
Install-Module -Name Az.ManagedServiceIdentity
Connect-AzAccount
Select-AzSubscription -Subscription b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-b5bXXXX

$rgname = "<ResourcegroupName>"
$location = "EastUS"
$kv = "<keyvaultName"
$appgwName = "<AppGw>"

$identity = New-AzUserAssignedIdentity -Name "appgwKeyVaultIdentity" -Location $location -ResourceGroupName $rgname
$keyVault = New-AzKeyVault -Name $kv -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Location $location
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $kv -PermissionsToSecrets get -ObjectId $identity.PrincipalId
$policy = New-AzKeyVaultCertificatePolicy -ValidityInMonths 12 `
  -SubjectName "CN=www.contoso11.com" -IssuerName self `
  -RenewAtNumberOfDaysBeforeExpiry 30
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $kv -EmailAddress <Your Email address> -PermissionsToCertificates create,get,list
$certificate = Add-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $kv -Name "cert1" -CertificatePolicy $policy
$certificate = Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $kv -Name "cert1"
#$secretId = $certificate.SecretId.Replace($certificate.Version, "")
```

[image]

In portal certificate was created successfully like below:

[image]

To extract the root certificate from the keyvault Make use of below powershell script:

```
$vaultName = '<YourVault>'
$certificateName = '<YourCert>'
$password = '<YourPwd>'

$pfxSecret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName -Name $certificateName -AsPlainText
$secretByte = [Convert]::FromBase64String($pfxSecret)
$x509Cert = New-Object Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$x509Cert.Import($secretByte, $null, [Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable)
$pfxFileByte = $x509Cert.Export([Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12, $password)

#Write to a file
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("C:\Temp\YourCertificateName.pfx", $pfxFileByte)
```

[image]

In folder certificates got exported successfully like below:
[image]

.
***Reference***:

[TLS termination using PowerShell - Azure Application Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-ssl-powershell)

Comment: Thanks Imran, but my issue is to upload the root certificate in backend settings and not in listener settings. As for listener, I was able to upload the certificate from key vault using ARM template. But there isn't any option to extract the root certificate in .cer and upload in the backend settings of application gateway.
I want to use https in backend settings that's why I need to upload root CA certificate in backend settings.

Comment: Are you looking only for key vault certificate ..For application gateway to upload the root certificate in backend settings we can use a self-signed certificate check [This](https://i.imgur.com/Xv4SGOR.png)